# rebuild table cells in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that when loaded gets data from a web-service and stores it locally in an NSMutableArray, once that is loaded I need to loop through that data to build my table cells.

I have all of the code for looping through my array working fine I just need to know how to fire my controller to rebuild the table so my it displays my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions here for creating a UITableViewDataSource class, works like a champ!

[UITableViewDataSource simplified](http://wjlafrance.net/?p=51)

Answer (score 4):

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I tried the above and it just crashes, where  do I setup the table view to have a datasource and will a NSMutableArray work for that?

Comment: it is an NSMutableArry of objects

Comment: Have you implemented your UITableViewDataSource methods to use your NSMutableArray? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDatasource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I think it's the link below I need, where do implement this? In the table view controller itself?    
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingTableDataSource.html

Answer (score 0):

After saving the datas in mutatable array after calling webservices, call tableview reloadData

```
[self.tableView reloadData];



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [datas count];
}
```

Make sure that you update the mutable array "datas" value after storing content in mutable array, such as datas will have the web service  contents.

[Here](http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/) is sample program of parsing and displaying the parsed content in table, you can refer it how they are reloading their table after parsing

All the best.